# Delete cell content in a WPF DataGrid when the Delete Key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Any idea on how I can achieve the following in a .Net 4 DataGrid:

```
private void grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;

        if (cell == null) { return; }

        if (!cell.IsReadOnly && cell.IsEnabled)
        {
            // Set the cell content (and the property of the object binded to it)
            // to null
        }
    }
}
```

This behavior should work with any cell, so I don't want to hardcode column or property names.

EDIT: Solution I came up with:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
{
    DataGridCell cell = e.OriginalSource as DataGridCell;

     if (cell == null) { return; }

     if (!cell.IsReadOnly && cell.IsEnabled)
     {
          TextBlock tb = cell.Content as TextBlock;

          if (tb != null)
          {
               Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(tb, TextBlock.TextProperty);

               if (binding == null) { return; }

               BindingExpression exp = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(tb, TextBlock.TextProperty);

               PropertyInfo info = exp.DataItem.GetType().GetProperty(binding.Path.Path);

               if (info == null) { return; }

               info.SetValue(exp.DataItem, null, null);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be pretty complicated, depending on the template of the cell, etc.

I'd imagine you'd have to use various `BindingOperations` methods (`BindingOperations.GetBinding`, `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression`, etc) to mess with the bound value?

Answer (score 3):

There a couple of things I had to do to get this to work:

1. Filter out delete key presses when editing (couldn't find an obvious way to detect if
   in editing mode):

   ```
   private bool _isEditing = false;
   private void datagrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
   {   _isEditing = true; }

   private void datagrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
   {   _isEditing = false; }
   ```
2. Handle the KeyUp message (KeyDown message was handled by datagrid):

   ```
   private void dataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (!_isEditing && e.Key == Key.Delete && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
       {
           foreach (var cellInfo in dataGrid.SelectedCells)
           {
              var column = cellInfo.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
              if (column != null)
              {
                 var binding = column.Binding as Binding;
                 if (binding != null)
                     BindingHelper.SetSource(cellInfo.Item, binding, null);
              }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use a framework helper class to route the value = null to the underlying view model

   ```
   public class BindingHelper: FrameworkElement
   {
      public static void SetSource(object source, Binding binding, object value)
      {
          var fe = new BindingHelper();
          var newBinding = new Binding(binding.Path.Path)
          {
              Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
              Source = source,
          };
          fe.SetBinding(ValueProperty, newBinding);
          fe.Value = value;
       }

       #region Value Dependency Property
       public object Value
       {
           get { return (object)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
           set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
       }

       public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(BindingHelper));
       #endregion
   }
   ```